# Composer: Override Transitive Dependency on PHP Version

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

I'm working on a project that uses guzzlehttp/guzzle.

While our production servers use PHP 5.4, our build box is still on 5.3, so when it runs a `composer install`, we see the following error:

```
guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.x-dev requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
```

Is there any way to override this? I've requiring php 5.3 "as" 5.4.0, but it then complained that the package 'php' couldn't be found.

It seems that requiring a PHP version is a special case of a package and doesn't allow the same overrides provided for normal packages. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way around this.

The problem is: How should Composer know about the PHP that is supposed to execute the code in contrast to the PHP that is just grapping it's dependencies. Currently there is no way to override either PHP versions or installed extensions.

And where should this override be put? It's wrong to put it into the `composer.json`, because that would change the detected PHP version Composer assumes, and will lead to conflicts. It should probably be some sort of configuration of the local Composer instance that is being used to override the assumed PHP version.

I'd suggest upgrading your build box to 5.4 or install an additional version of PHP 5.4 that is only used for Composer.

How would you detect version conflicts on that build box during test execution if you do not use the PHP version that is supposed to run the code?